# Gerunds and complements in a sentence

Tags: gerunds, complements

What's the role of the word *flying* in both sentences and *drones* in the latter, please?

- Troy enjoys flying.
- Losi's hobby is flying drones.

And how to differentiate between a gerund and a complement in sentences?

Answer (score 2):

[i] Troy enjoys flying. 
[ii] Losi's hobby is flying drones.

'Semantic role' is the underlying relationship that a participant has with the main verb in a clause.¹ But I guess that's not what you're asking for; I believe by 'role' you mean the grammatical functions of the phrases.

*Complement* is a **grammatical function** that has a close relationship with the verb. It's usually obligatory. So it's clear that 'flying' in [i] is complement of the verb *enjoy*.

*Gerund* is a **verb form**.² So it's inappropriate to say '*flying* is a verb functioning as a gerund'. *Flying* in [i] is a verb (in the form of gerund) functioning as complement of the verb 'enjoy'.

*Drones* in [ii] is a noun that functions as object of the verb *flying*.³ *Flying*, on the other hand, is a verb (gerund) that heads the gerund clause *flying drones*, which functions as the complement of the copula *is*.

---

¹<sub>More info is [here](http://www.glossary.sil.org/term/semantic-role).</sub>

²<sub>I don't distinguish between 'gerund' and 'present participle'. So what you call 'present participle' is a gerund here.</sub>

³<sub>An object is a kind of complement. So it's also okay to say *drones* is a complement of the verb *flying*.</sub>

Comment: Good answer. +1 Nice to see some proper grammar on here.